# opening and closing balance query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out the opening and closing balance based on the customer and their daily wise cr/dr transaction.

closing= opening+db -cr  and

opening should the closing of previous date and if no previous records is available for that customer it should 0.

```
create table pj_test_cr_dr(
    cst_name varchar2(100),
    txn_dt number(8),
    cr_amt number(22,7),
    dr_amt number(22,7)
    );

insert into pj_test_cr_dr 
    values ('c1', to_char(sysdate-5,'yyyymmdd'),200,0);
insert into pj_test_cr_dr 
    values ('c1', to_char(sysdate-5,'yyyymmdd'),300,0);
insert into pj_test_cr_dr 
    values ('c1', to_char(sysdate-5,'yyyymmdd'),0,2000);
insert into pj_test_cr_dr 
    values ('c1', to_char(sysdate-4,'yyyymmdd'),100,0);
insert into pj_test_cr_dr 
    values ('c1', to_char(sysdate-4,'yyyymmdd'),400,0);
insert into pj_test_cr_dr 
    values ('c1', to_char(sysdate-4,'yyyymmdd'),0,2000);
insert into pj_test_cr_dr 
    values ('c1', to_char(sysdate-3,'yyyymmdd'),2000,2000);
insert into pj_test_cr_dr 
    values ('c1', to_char(sysdate-3,'yyyymmdd'),4000,2000);
insert into pj_test_cr_dr 
    values ('c1', to_char(sysdate-2,'yyyymmdd'),5000,0);
commit;

select  cst_name, txn_dt, sum(dr_amt) dr,sum(cr_amt) cr
    from pj_test_cr_dr 
    group by cst_name, txn_dt 
    order by 1,2;
```

query output

[image]

expected result :

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    cst_name,
    debit,
    credit,
    lag(closing,1,0) over (partition by cst_name order by txn_dt) opening,
    closing
from (
    select 
        cst_name,
        txn_dt,
        sum(dr_amt) debit,
        sum(cr_amt) credit,
        sum(sum(dr_amt - cr_amt)) over (partition by cst_name order by txn_dt) closing
    from pj_test_cr_dr
    where txn_dt > 20170130
    group by cst_name, txn_dt
) t;
```

Also notice the `partition by cst_name`. I think you want to keep values of different customers separate.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be correct, data got messed up after adding data for 1 more day.  All I'm looking is there will be customer and day wise dr/cr and opening for next day should be closing of previous day.

Comment: @pjha - Updated my answer. Try now

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this - all in one query (no subqueries) and only with analytic functions (not mixing with aggregates - other than selecting `distinct` which is needed because there may be multiple transactions per day).

```
select distinct cst_name, txn_dt,
         coalesce( sum(dr_amt - cr_amt) over (partition by cst_name order by txn_dt 
             range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0 )       as op_bal,
         sum(dr_amt) over (partition by cst_name, txn_dt)                  as daily_dr,
         sum(cr_amt) over (partition by cst_name, txn_dt)                  as daily_cr,
         sum(dr_amt - cr_amt) over (partition by cst_name order by txn_dt) as cl_bal
from     pj_test_cr_dr
order by cst_name, txn_dt   --   if needed
;

CST_NAME     TXN_DT     OP_BAL   DAILY_DR   DAILY_CR     CL_BAL
-------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
c1         20170131          0       2000        500       1500
c1         20170201       1500       2000        500       3000
c1         20170202       3000       4000       6000       1000
c1         20170203       1000          0       5000      -4000
```